# Using CSS3 :nth-child() Selector

Tags: html, css

My CSS/HTML here :

```css
    p:nth-child(2) {
        background: #ff0000;
    }
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
```

And result is show red color in line `<p>The first paragraph.</p>`

Why ? I think It must show red in line `<p>The second paragraph.</p>`.

Comment: Because it is the second child. Did you mean `nth-of-type(2)`?

Comment: '<h1>' is parent of '<p>' ?

Comment: put all the paragraphs in a div than this css gonna work

Comment: Read the documentation for `nth-child`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nth-child() selects the particular element if it is the nth(in your case 2nd) child of the parent.

Here you need to use nth-of-type() that will select the element type (let's say p) if it is nth(in your case 2nd) of its type in its parent

```css
p:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:nth-of-type(2)`

```css
p:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent.

Tip: Look at the :nth-of-type() selector to select the element that is the nth child, of a particular type, of its parent.

source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 0):

for that result use `:nth-of-type( 2 )`, `h1` is also a child.